# Missing api-prefix in request from ReferenceArrayInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin, api-platform.com

I try to use the ReferenceArrayInput-element from react-admin to edit a OneToMany relationship.

The options for the multi-select input are loaded corectly but the selection isn't.
For some reason, `react-admin` tries to access the `propery_values` without the api-prefix ("/api/property_values"):

```
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:8002/4' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The Stacktrace:

```
index.js:1 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at fetchJsonLd.ts:17:1
    at step (tslib.es6.js:102:1)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:83:1)
    at tslib.es6.js:76:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Module.__awaiter (tslib.es6.js:72:1)
    at fetchJsonLd (fetchJsonLd.ts:12:1)
    at _default (fetchHydra.js:37:1)
    at dataProvider.js:548:1
    at async Promise.all (:3000/index 1)
```

When i replace the `reference` in the `ReferenceArrayInput` with "PropertyValue" (which is neither the name of the endpoint nor the resource, react-admin tries the following request:
`https://localhost:8002/api/PropertyValues?order%5Bid%5D=DESC&page=1&itemsPerPage=25`
This looks better but is obviously not the right path (should be "/api/property_values").

I use the `ResourceGuesser` from Api-Platform and the data from the `/api/properties/{id}` endpoint looks as follows:

```json
{
   "@context":"\/api\/contexts\/Property",
   "@id":"\/api\/properties\/2",
   "@type":"Property",
   "id":2,
   "name":"Anwendungszweck",
   "type":"enum",
   "propertyValues":[
      {
         "@id":"\/api\/property_values\/3",
         "@type":"PropertyValue",
         "id":3,
         "value":"Ansprache",
         "attributes":[
            
         ]
      },
      {
         "@id":"\/api\/property_values\/4",
         "@type":"PropertyValue",
         "id":4,
         "value":"Musik",
         "attributes":[
            
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The important part is inside the `PropertyValuesEdit` where i allready tried to debug with `JSON.stringify()`.

```js
import React from "react"
import { parseHydraDocumentation } from "@api-platform/api-doc-parser"
import ResourceGuesserPropertyValue from "./PropertyValue"
import { HydraAdmin, fetchHydra, hydraDataProvider, ResourceGuesser, EditGuesser, InputGuesser
} from "@api-platform/admin"
import {ReferenceArrayInput, SelectArrayInput} from 'react-admin'

const entrypoint = "https://localhost:8001/api"

const dataProvider = hydraDataProvider({
    entrypoint,
    httpClient: fetchHydra,
    apiDocumentationParser: parseHydraDocumentation,
    mercure: true,
    useEmbedded: true,
})

const PropertyEdit = props => (
    <EditGuesser {...props}>
        <InputGuesser source={"name"} />
        <InputGuesser source={"type"} />
        <InputGuesser source={"description"} />
        <ReferenceArrayInput
            source="propertyValues"
            reference="property_values"
            parse={(value) => value && value.map((v) => ({ id: v }))}
            format={(value) => value && value.map((v) => v.id)}
        >
            <SelectArrayInput optionText="value" />
        </ReferenceArrayInput>
    </EditGuesser>
)

export default function App(props) {
    return <HydraAdmin
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        entrypoint={entrypoint}>
        <ResourceGuesser name={"properties"} edit={PropertyEdit} />
        <ResourceGuesserPropertyValue name="property_values" {...props} />
    </HydraAdmin>
}
```

Thanks for your Help!

#### snippet for "Jacer Omri"

This is pretty much the only generated code i can copy from the console.
The problem with this generated Code is, that the `property_values` are displayed as serialized json-objects.

```js
const PropertyEdit = props => (
    <EditGuesser {...props}>
        <InputGuesser source={"name"} />
        <InputGuesser source={"type"} />
        <InputGuesser source={"description"} />
        <InputGuesser source={"propertyValues"} />
    </EditGuesser>
);
```

Comment: This is not a direct answer, you are not supposed to used the guessers provided. You should copy the code printed out in the browser console and use it as a starting point for your components. In that case, you won't worry about not being able to customize any behaviour.

Comment: I understand your approach but i can't copy much more than this snippet of code from the console:  -> see added code in description...

The problem with this generated Code is, that the `property_values` are displayed as serialized json-objects.

I added a sentence to the description (second one) and replaced the code with a simplified version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if the data from `/api/properties/{id}` is like you have provided before, I think with these data from the endpoint, your PropertyEdit should be like:

```json
{
   "@context":"\/api\/contexts\/Property",
   "@id":"\/api\/properties\/2",
   "@type":"Property",
   "id":2,
   "name":"Anwendungszweck",
   "type":"enum",
   "propertyValues":[
      {
         "@id":"\/api\/property_values\/3",
         "@type":"PropertyValue",
         "id":3,
         "value":"Ansprache",
         "attributes":[
            
         ]
      },
      {
         "@id":"\/api\/property_values\/4",
         "@type":"PropertyValue",
         "id":4,
         "value":"Musik",
         "attributes":[
            
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

```
const PropertyEdit = props => (
    <EditGuesser {...props}>
        <InputGuesser source="name" />
        <InputGuesser source="type" />
        <InputGuesser source="description" />
        <SelectArrayInput source="propertyValues" choices="propertyValues" optionText="value" />
    </EditGuesser>
)
```

However, if you haven't embedded data but just IRI, with `useEmbedded` set to true,  you need to use the dot notation to display a field.
See https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/handling-relations/#display-a-field-of-an-embedded-relation at the second example (with `useEmbedded: true`).

Comment: As far as i see, the `SelectArrayInput` component can only be used if i fetch the `choices` on my own. `choices` is a required parameter.  
If the `choices` should be fetched automatically (via endpoint), one has to use the `ReferenceInput` to wrap it.  This is covered by the link that you sent my but there is no scenario with a "One-To-Many" relationship (`ReferenceArrayInput`).

Comment: Yes, I forgot the required choices. But, if your endpoint response is like you provided, you should use propertyValues for choices prop. In these data, propertyValues are deserialized, it's not an array of IRI but an array of propertyValue data with the value field. You don't need to fetch this data, you already have. I have updated my answer, let me know if I haven't understood something.

Comment: This makes no sense to me because the `propertyValues` array does not contain the possible choices. They have to be fetched.  
`propertyValues` contains the selected values.  
Anyway, i allready switched to pure `react-admin` (without `api-platform-admin`).  This seems the way to go for me.

Comment: Ok, obviously I did not understand all the points, sorry. Anyway, react-admin without api-platform-admin seems to be a better solution. I did the same thing on my project, it's easier.

Comment: No Problem!  
Interesting ;) Can you tell me, how your DataProvider looks like?  
I had to do some modifications because api-platform serves IRI's instead of ID's (i commented it): https://gist.github.com/71m024/2b78740ef69d186ccabb841ccb1fdc2c

Comment: I don't need to parse the ID from IRI. If I get a deserialized object, I have the ID. If I have an IRI, I call this IRI to get a deserialized object. I have one DataProvider per entity and I did a lot of work on my backend to have the correct deserialized objects and I wrote some proxy controllers for some cases. For a complex API, you can't work only with the basic API-P system that requires too many calls, in my view. It's a bit complicated to explain in a comment. gitlab.com/adynemo/comicsbox and gitlab.com/adynemo/comicsbox-api